# python pandas dataframe from list of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list as such:

`[[None, 'ASK', 'BID'], ['4Y', 343.545, 344.621],['7Y', 0.016, 0.015],['9Y', 99.9, 99.8]]`

and I would like to convert that into a dataframe as such:

`'4Y' | 'ASK' | 343.545
'4Y' | 'BID' | 344.621
'7Y' | 'ASK' | 0.016
'7Y' | 'BID' | 0.015
'9Y' | 'ASK' | 99.9
'9Y' | 'BID' | 99.8`

I've tried all sorts of "loopy" ways, but they seem terribly ugly and inefficient.

Comment: what's wrong with `pd.DataFrame(the_array)`?

Comment: how about that it doesn't produce the expected outcome for a candidate, mate?

Comment: Does any sublist can have None?

Comment: @DanielMesejo No, `None` is present only as the 0th element of the 0th sublist.

Comment: I don't think this question deserve downvoting. Someone may disagree with me. I give this an upvote to counteract the downvoting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume `l` is your list. Construct `df` and `melt`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l[1:], columns=l[0])
df.rename({None: 'Year'}, axis=1).melt('Year').sort_values('Year')

Out[477]:
  Year variable    value
0   4Y      ASK  343.545
3   4Y      BID  344.621
1   7Y      ASK    0.016
4   7Y      BID    0.015
2   9Y      ASK   99.900
5   9Y      BID   99.800
```

Answer (score 3):

Takse some time to see what you want:

```
arr[0][0] = 'idx'
(pd.DataFrame(arr[1:], columns=arr[0])
   .set_index('idx')
   .stack()
   .reset_index(name='value')
)
```

Output:

```
  idx level_1    value
0  4Y     ASK  343.545
1  4Y     BID  344.621
2  7Y     ASK    0.016
3  7Y     BID    0.015
4  9Y     ASK   99.900
5  9Y     BID   99.800
```

Comment: who said I downvoted? Not to mention that your question provide minimal information. You could have explained the out put.